# PHP moving files to root when uploaded by another web user

Tags: php, apache

We use a Java upload applet to let clients FTP files to our website.

For security, it uses a "web_user" (as created in PLESK) so this user gets their own area outside the main root e.g

```
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/web_users/clientuploaduser/
```

I'm trying to copy the files they upload backto the web root via php so we can use them e.g to

```
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/clientdropbox/
```

I can't seem to do so.

I can use main FTP account to go in and move the files that way as it has more permissions than the client one, but it's not particularly efficient and it's a little slow.

Is there a way I can use PHP to move those files? We have root access to the machine, so if there's permissions that can be changed, or something, then it's no issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get errors when you try to move them?

Comment: Not that I can see, it just fails to move.

Answer (score 0):

The user that moves the file must have read permissions on /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com, web_users, and httpdocs and read/write permissions on httpdocs/clientdropbox/.  A lot of times the read permissions on the lower directories are overlooked.

Comment: So if I add apache or psacln to the web user group that might do the trick?